# Python -Need to match DNA from 2 inputs

Tags: python-3.x

Currently working on a project to do the following:

- Ask user to enter a  first strand of dna
- Checks to make sure that the strand is valid (A,C,T and G, lower case is also accepted).
- After first strand is entered, the program asks for the second strand and checks if is
  complementary
- A is Complementary of T, T to A. and G is complementary with C and C to G.
- Result should be:

Enter first sequence of dna: ATGC 
Enter second sequence of dna:TACG 
"They are Complementary"

Enter first sequence of dna: GTC 
Enter second sequence of dna:GAC 
not complementary.

Enter second sequence of dna: exit 
exiting program.....

```
#Code starts here:

def compare_DNA_lenght(dna1,dna2):  

    if len(dna1) != len(dna2):
        print ('Input sequence incorrect') 

def complement(sequence):
    """ (str) -> str"""

    replace={'a':'t','t':'a','c':'g','g':'c'}
    complement=''
    print('in the loop',sequence)
    for i in sequence:
        complement=complement+replace[i]

    print(sequence)

while (dna1 != "exit" and dna2 != "exit"):

    dna1= input('Please enter your first sequence:')
    dna2= input('Please enter your second sequence:')

    dna1=dna1.lower() 
    dna2=dna2.lower()

    if (dna1 =="exit" and dna2 =="exit"):
        print ("Exiting program")

    if(dna2 == complement):
        print ("They are complementary")

    elif(dna2 != complement):
        print ("Not a complementary strand")

    print (complement)
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know how to match the sequence for dna1 to dna2 to see if they are complementary of each other. I am new to python and the book is limited in this.

Comment: Maverick, in your example the two strands are NOT complementary to each other, unless you read the upper strand from left to right (5'->3') and the lower strand from right to left (5'->3'). You have to turn one of them around to make them complementary. Invert one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on [how while loops work in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop). In the meantime, here's the basic structure of one:

```
while condition:
    code
```

Keep in mind that you should always make sure that `condition` will eventually evaluate to `false`, otherwise you'll end up in an infinite loop, causing your program to hang. A simple example would be printing the numbers `1` through `5`:

```
i = 1
while (i <= 5):
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
```

Eventually, `i` is `6`, so the `while` loop will not execute the code inside, because `6` is not equal to or less than `5`.

Before your `while` loop, you need to declare your `dna1` and `dna2` variables so your program doesn't throw an error saying it can't find those variables.

```
dna1= input('Please enter your first sequence:')
dna2= input('Please enter your second sequence:')
    while (dna1 != "exit" and dna2 != "exit"):
```

Additionally, you don't need to check if both strings say "exit" to break out of the loop. Just one should suffice.

```
if (dna1 =="exit" or dna2 =="exit"):
```

On an unrelated note, it's considered good practice to spell your method names correctly. "compare_DNA_lenght" should probably be "compare_DNA_length".

Comment: Thank you, I do understand that. However, if I have an 2 different inputs as a string. Should I use a for loop? or should I split each in a list then compare one to the other. Because in this case, I have to DNA sequences only (ATCG) and they must be complementary. Therefore if input1 = ATCG then input2 should only be = TAGC to print "They are complementary"

Comment: For and while loops are, in most cases, equivalent, so it shouldn't matter which one you use as long as your logic is sound. From what I understand, you have your original DNA sequence, the second input, which you're checking to see if it's complementary to the first, and a third generated string which is the *actual* complementary sequence. If this is the case, all you need to do is compare the second input string with the generated complementary sequence. `if(dna2 == complement) return True`

Comment: Yes, I will try this. But, I will ad an else statement to say if they are not complementary then print ("Not complementary") inside a while loop, since the program has to keep running until a person enters exit.

Comment: In that case, be sure that your `while` loop is checking the user input, and exiting when appropriate. It looks like you might want something like `while (dna1 != "exit" and dna2 != "exit")`.

Comment: Thank you, this way I will run until the user enters exit

Comment: Hi Desertlvy, I have incorporated your code and added some of my own, however it does not run. Is there something I should fix here?

Comment: `if (dna1 =="exit" and dna2 =="exit")` Anything look fishy about that? Please be more specific - what does "it does not run" mean? Does the entire script not run? Does a certain part not execute as expected?

Comment: I actually fixed the code above, but the whole code in not running.it keeps saying "  while (dna1 != "exit" and dna2 != "exit"):
NameError: name 'dna1' is not defined".

Comment: Right, this is because you need to define those variables before you reference them. You can easily do this by adding `dna1= input('Please enter your first sequence:')
    dna2= input('Please enter your second sequence:')` before the `while` loop.

Comment: I did this right now, but the loops runs forever, let me change fix my elif statements.

Comment: Look at this line: `if (dna1 =="exit" and dna2 =="exit")` Notice anything weird? Maybe it should be `or` not `and`?

Comment: Sure, I also did change it to or but still runs forever. Also, it seems like the logic isn't right because when I type AT in the first sequence and TA in the second sequence, it keeps saying they are not complementary, when it should say "complementary"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50990/discussion-between-desertivy-and-maverick)

Comment: Hi Desertlvy, I am almost about done with my code, but the problem I am having is that it does not loop after the first and second DNA strand is imputed and it does not quit when enter 'quit' I will update my code for you to see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51070/discussion-between-desertivy-and-maverick)

Answer (score 1):

> **Check valid DNA strand**

So the first thing you need to do is to check whether or not the used input is a valid DNA. Since a DNA only contains A,T,G and C we can check the validity by creating a formula that checks for A,T,G and C. True if these are present and False if any letters other than A,T,G and C.

```
def is_dna_strand(x):

"""

(str) -> bool
Returns True if the DNA strand entered contains only the DNA bases.

>>> is_dna_strand("AGTC")
'True'
>>> is_dna_strand("AGHFJ")
'False'

"""
    a=x.lower()
i=0
while i != (len(a)):
    if ((a[i])!= "a") and ((a[i])!="t")and((a[i])!="c")and((a[i])!="g"):
        return False
    i+=1

return True
```

> **Check the base pairs**

```
def is_base_pair(x,y):

"""
(str,str) -> bool
Returs true if two parameters form a base pair.

>>> is_base_pair("A","T")
'True'
>>> is_base_pair("A","G")
'False'
"""

    a=x.lower()
    b=y.lower()

    if a=="a" and b=="t":
        return True
    elif a=="t" and b=="a":
        return True
    elif a=="c" and b=="g":
        return True
    elif a=="g" and b=="c":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

> **Check whether it's a valid DNA or not.**
>   So the final step in this process is check the validity of the entire molecule.

```
def is_dna(x,y):

"""

(str,str) -> bool
Returs true if the two strands form a properly base-paired DNA.

>>> is_dna("AAGTC","TTCAG")
'True'
>>> is_dna("TCGA","TCAG")
'False'

"""
i=0
j=0
if len(x)==len(y):
    while i < (len(x)):
        b=x[i]
        c=y[i]
        i=i+1
        return is_base_pair(b,c)
else:
    return False
```